# Separating thousands using gspread formatting

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a number values which I am trying to format as a currency with a thousand separator in google sheets using gspread and gspread_formatting:

```
A

151644
56464
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
A

£ 151,644
£ 56,464
```

I tried:

```
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£#.##0.'}})
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£###. ###0'}})
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£#.###'}})
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£#.#'}})
worksheet.format('A', {'numberFormat': {'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£###'}})
```

Which none of return the expected result, I couldn't find documentation about the formatting patterns to have a thousand separators.

How could I achieve this using `gspread_formatting` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `How could I achieve this using gspread_formatting package?`, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
format_cell_range(worksheet, 'A', cellFormat(numberFormat={'type': 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£ #,###'}))
```

#### Note:

- I added this answer as the additional information because I thought that when various approaches are shown, they might be useful for other users.

#### References:

- [gspread-formatting](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting)
- [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#NumberFormatType)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the format using:

```
worksheet.format('A', 
{'numberFormat': 
{'type' : 'CURRENCY', 'pattern': '£ #,###'}})
```

Not sure if this is the ideal format but it works.